# Why can't I change string to integer

Tags: scanf, atoi

I'm new here

I've been trying to get some input from a txt file and change the data to integer
but I got stuck here.

```
#define MAX_LEN 100
#define MAX_NUM 10
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *in;
    in=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char inNum[MAX_LEN];
    int number=11;
    int i=0;
    while(EOF!=fscanf(in,"%s\n",inNum))
    {
        number=atoi(inNum);
        printf("%s %d %d\n",inNum,i,number);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the input is

```
123231
1235992
513234
```

but the result is

```
123231 0 0
1235992 1 1235992
513234 2 513234
```

I couldn't find the reason why the first line input changes to 0....
please help me

Comment: the atoi function is failing and returning 0 for the first input for some reason.

Comment: What is the output if you repeat "number=atoi(inNum); and the printf()"?

Comment: Also, how about adding strlen( inNum ) to the printf()?

Comment: Oh, ok I think my input txt file has some problem.....thank you so much